# Install GMS core Packages on brand-new Huawei

Tags: google-play-store, huawei

Like some people here before me, I have problems installing GMS core packages on my brand-new Huawei that I bought some weeks ago in China. (EMUI 5.1, Android 7.0, Model number TRT-AL00A, Build Number TRT-AL00AC00B210)

I read through some of the posts here and in other forums, but whenever I tried to install the downloads, I got an error message. (I need to admit, I am not a very tech-savvy person..)

So I guess the main problem is that my Huawei version is simply too new - is that correct? :O Has anyone encountered similar problems or discovered a solution?

Thanks for your consideration!
All the best,
Tobias

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! To install GApps, they need to be "flashed" to the system partition (or you need root powers to place them manually). For details, see e.g. our [google-apps tag-wiki](/tags/google-apps/info). Alternatively, you could try [microG](https://microg.org/), which is an open source alternative to the proprietary Google Services Framework.

Answer (score 1):

You can use YalpStore instead of google play store: 
https://github.com/yeriomin/YalpStore
https://github.com/yeriomin/YalpStore/releases
https://f-droid.org/packages/com.github.yeriomin.yalpstore

Just install the yalpstore zip as you would install a google zip.

Please do not use androidapksfree.com . 
Apps from androidapksfree do not come directly via google and can therefore be maliciously modified, malware. Apps via yalpstore come directly and can't be modified.

Also distributing apps via other channels like androidapksfree can be considered a copyright infringement (= crime) - apps from yalpstore come directly from google and can only be considered "violation of google terms of service". This is far less than a crime.

Answer (score 0):

GMS services have to be installed in /system. 
To be able to install anything in /system, you have to either unlock the bootloader of your smartphone ('clean' way) or root your smartphone ('dirty' way). 
After unlocking the bootloader, you need a recovery that can install the GMS zip package. I only know TWRP. 
So: 
1. Is your bootloader unlocked? Search google to find out: 
- how to check if your bootloader is unlocked (on your device or similar devices)
- how to unlock it (search on your manufacturers website)
2. Do you have a recovery that can install zip packages? TWRP would be such a recovery. Search google to find out: 
- how to boot into recovery on your device (to find out if a suitable one exists)
- how to flash a suitable recovery with fastboot ("flash recovery fastboot")

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Currently the GMS Core installer is not compatible for HUAWEI {EMUI 5.1, Android 7.0) so you'll face problems when downloading the GMS Installer.
So if you want to install Apps like Whatsapp, Facebook and Messenger, you need to download the APK before installing them. The link as below:
https://www.androidapksfree.com/apk/whatsapp-apk-latest-version-download/ 
https://www.androidapksfree.com/apk/facebook-apk-latest-version-download/
https://www.androidapksfree.com/apk/facebook-messenger-apk-latest-version-download/