# Installing Google Services and Google Play store on Huawei Y6P

Tags: huawei, google-play-services

I recently purchased a Huaway Y6P without realizing that it comes without Google apps. I am situated in Europe, not China, and I am used to using Google where I have all my data.

I have followed several guides online and all have failed. They all center around installing the Google Play Services apk and then the Google Play store apk, but they all point to different dodgy/old apk binaries.
This is what I have done:

1. I have enabled installing apps from untrusted sources.
2. I have installed Google Play Services 21.33.56 (the latest at this time) from apkmirror.com. I chose the version for Android 10, built for `armeabi-v7a`.
3. Once I install this, I get a new option under "Settings" -> "Accounts" for a "Google" account. Once I touch "Google", the activity seems to crash and return me back to the accounts menu.
4. I can install other google apps like play, chrome, maps, etc, but they all fail to load without error messages. I suspect this is because the Google Services app is not working and I have not been able to login to my account.

Can someone please shed some light on this? Am I installing a build for an incorrect architecture?

I'm beginning to regret buying a Huawei phone. I never would have guessed it's so hard to connect to my google calendar, keep, contacts, and other online data that I have on Google. Please help!

Comment: I just ran Droid Info and found out that the Instruction sets listed are: `armeabi-v7a` and `armeabi`.

Comment: Related, sadly: [Google's Huawei ban, how will this hit Huawei, since Android is open source?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/212659/44325). Anyway, hopefully [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/189124/44325) may help, though unlocking the bootloader to flash a custom recovery (and additionally getting root access) might be another big issue.

Comment: @AndrewT. Oh no! I hadn't realized this was going on! So it seems there is no solution at all?

Comment: There's [another question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/232190/44325) about rooting and unlocking the bootloader of modern Huawei devices, and seems it might still be possible. Though, your mileage may vary.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try to root the phone one way or another and see if that helps.

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/241464/is-there-an-official-source-of-google-play-store-service-framework-gms-or-trust#comment320944_241464